# How do I properly leave a conversation in Cyberpunk 2077?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

For reference this is on PC, on a keyboard and mouse.

It seems that the only way to leave a conversation is to just... walk away? But that seems a little odd to me, as when you approach that same person again, the same conversation stuff shows up. This is particularly odd when there are other items near the person (the first time you come across the fight-ring coach, near V's apartment) that I cannot pick up, because the game locks me into the conversation options.

Is there a button to leave a conversation properly, or is walking away from the person the actual right way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're holding a conversation with somebody then walking away from the conversation is actually the correct way to end the conversation. There isn't a way to politely end the conversation.

Note that if you actually walk away while they're trying to talk to you that your current position in the conversation is saved and picked up on next time you talk to that person - similar to how phone calls with automatically hang up if you trigger particular actions, only for you to automatically call the person back once the interruption has finished.

Comment: Absolutely wild lol. Even Witcher 3 let you leave conversations with dialogue, although it could be argued that conversations were different in that game. Oh well, I'll keep being unintentionally rude to the people I talk to, thanks!

Comment: I find this most annoying when there is an interactive object like a door or an item I can pick up near a person I am talking to. I walk away to leave the conversation, but when I walk back, it often auto-picks up the conversation again instead of letting me open the door or pick up the item.